# Facebook HTML5 activity feed custom css

Tags: css, facebook, plugins

Is there a way to add a custom css to the HTML5 [Facebook activity plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/)?

This is the code of it:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=123456789";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-activity" data-width="300" data-height="300" data-header="true" data-recommendations="false"></div>
```

I'd love to show bigger images and change the color of the links.
Thanks. Uli

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you should just be able to hook into the classes that Facebook provides on the elements such as:

```
.fbWidgetTitle
{
 // Change styles on the title of the activity box
}
```

Use Firebug or whatever tool you have to check the source and see what you're able to hook into.

Comment: Tried it but the image size does not change. I got this from FireBug but maybe I'm missing something? **.fbImageContainer {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
}** (I'd like to change the small preview image  to 100x100 px)

Comment: That adjusts the image container but you also need to adjust the size of the actual image inside there: `.fbImageContainer img{ /*styles*/}`

Comment: Tried it but the image still stays at the original size. Any ideas what else to try out?

Comment: Are you defining styles that are already set? If so you might need to use the `!important` decleration on your styles.

Comment: If you've got a live page that you're working on, it might help for me to take a look.

Comment: I set one up here: http://jsfiddle.net/py47L/4/ - I'd like to archive that images are displayed at 100x100 px and the links are black instead of blue. Any help appreciated!